# Jackson ignores end of body

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a problem with fasterxml Jackson where it ignores everything after the object like:

```
{
   "startIndex": 0,
   "length": 10,
   "gotoLastPage": false
}
whatever comes here is ignored
```

I don't know if is possible to throw an error in this case. If the unexpected message is at the beginning it fails as I want. The configuration property **DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES** is set to true.

Comment: Is it possible to get a complete `JSON`? What you provided so far is simply a `syntax error`. Curly braces mark an object. Everything which is outside does not belong to the object. http://json.org/

Comment: It's a really simple body, seems that fasterxml is not checking if is something left after the object.

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma "," after the line ' "gotoLastPage": false,'

Answer (score 0):

As I see. The parser itself works very simple.
The object is between first "{" and "}", all, what is outside is ignored. Because it is not he object scope any more. Otherwise you need to have a list of the objects, and the list itself is the object.